# How to get the properties of an .ai or .eps file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, eps

How can I get the properties of ai (Adobe Illustrator) or eps file i.e resolution in dpi etc.
I need to check this properties when uploading file to server.

Also is there any DLL to convert ai/eps to standards image format(jpg, gif, png etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

```
use ImageMagickNET.dll through this you can convert the .ai or .eps files into .jpg format..
```

c# code:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Process ffmpeg;
        string video;
        string thumb;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ffmpeg = new Process();

            ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = "convert \"" + .ai file path + "\" -background white -flatten -density 300 -colors 512 -antialias  -normalize -units PixelsPerInch -quality 100 -colorspace RGB -resize 3425x3425  \"D:\\GRAPHICS SEARCH ENGINE\\GRAPHICS IMAGES\\AI\\" convert.jpg\"";

            ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = ("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ImageMagick-6.5.3-Q16\\convert.exe");
            ffmpeg.Start();

         }
    }
```

To get the ai files properties like width, height,number of pages and title,
use itextsharp.dll

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text; 
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace pdfreared { public partial class Form1 : Form { public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"D:\Files Formats\Icon.ai");
        int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
        label4.Text = n.ToString();

        // size of the first page
        Rectangle psize = reader.GetPageSize(1);
        float width = psize.Width;
        label1.Text ="Width= " + Convert.ToString(width);
        float height = psize.Height;
        label2.Text = "Height = " + Convert.ToString(height);
      //  reader.Metadata.

        Console.WriteLine("Size of page 1 of {0} => {1} × {2}", n, width, height);
        // file properties
        Dictionary<string, string> infodict = reader.Info;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in infodict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " => " + kvp.Value);
            label3.Text = kvp.Key + " => " + kvp.Value;


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use "identify -verbose image.eps" to give the metadata information of EPS file and AI file.